# Removing spikes from surface grid plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw some 3d objects with pgfplots. These objects are defined by surfaces described by means of *(x, y, z)* coordinates which I imported from MATLAB:

```
\addplot3[surf, faceted color=black, fill=white, thick, z buffer=sort, mesh/rows=8]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
x   y   z   c\\
0   0   80  80\\
2.25    0   80  80\\
2.25    0   81.5    81.5\\
0   0   81.5    81.5\\
% [...] %
0   0   81.5    81.5\\
};
```

This works fine, but the result is nasty because of those spikes that you see in the grid, which I'm trying to remove. I've tried either with the `smooth` and the `rounded corners` keys, but the first for some reason removes the white filling (which I want) and the second does nothing.

[image: Spikes_pgfplots_surf]

Could someone please suggest a way to overcome this problem? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: solved with `miter limits=1`.

Comment: `line-join=round`?

Comment: Maybe `miter limit=1` helps as well

Comment: Many thanks @ChristianFeuersänger it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect is caused by a pdf feature which combines start- and end point of adjacent lines: the "overshoots" appear because of the small-scaled changes and the default configuration of line-endings.

Use `miter limit=1` in order to configure less restrictive settings and it should be fine.

Details about this parameter (and its friends) can be found in pgfmanual.pdf